# jshint - firefox addon - 'self' is not defined

Tags: firefox-addon, jshint

I'm writing a basic firefox addon and jshint complains about self not being defined.

I use self in the content script like that:

```
self.port.emit("message", "payload");
```

I tried to setup the moz options in my .jshint.rc file but I still get the error. Should I add 'self' in the 'globals' in .jshint.rc or am I missing something else?

Comment: If `self` is a global variable provided by the environment then yes, just add it to your `globals` directive.

Comment: I believe that this is not an error because `self` is provided by firefox and doesn't need a global definition, it is working just in the fly.

Comment: It looks like SDK and `self` in this case is set by addon SDK in Firefox SDK environment.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Thank you, could you please put your comment as an answer so that I can choose it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `self` is a global variable provided by the environment then yes, you just need to add it to your `globals` directive. You can either do that in your `.jshintrc` config file:

```
{
  "globals": {
    "self": false
  }
}
```

Or inline in the file itself:

```
/*globals self: false */
```

The `false` in the examples above tell JSHint that the variable is read-only. Any attempt to assign to it will trigger a warning. If you do need to assign to it you can use `true` instead.